# Get date string without separators in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to remove the `-`'s from the following string:

```
Date.today.to_s #=> "2016-04-11"
```

using a single line of code.

Expected Result is

"2016 04 11"

Comment: Removing characters (as stated in your question) and converting them to spaces (as stated in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540832/rails-4-2-6-get-date-without-special-characters#comment60683750_36540881)) is not the same. Please clarify your question. What's your expected result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `strftime` function to format dates:

```
Date.today.strftime("%Y%m%d") # => "20160411"
```

Docs: http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

**edit:**

For spaces:

```
Date.today.strftime("%Y %m %d") # => "2016 04 11"
```

Comment: In my view, this is a better answer

Comment: umm why? can you explain?

Comment: dkp's answer is more precise to what i need. but still this is helpful thanks.
i still need the spaces between the dates.

Comment: Please follow the api docs link in the answer. strftime method formats date according to the directives in the given format string.

Comment: if you need spaces between the date parts then use proper format string with spaces: Date.today.strftime("%Y %m %d")

Comment: `strftime` provides more flexibility in how you can format dates by using tokens as placeholders for parts of the date. For instance`%Y` is a placeholder for year, `%m` is a placeholder for a 2-digit representation of month, etc. You can mix and combine with other parts of a string to generate more dynamic results. For instance, you can probably guess what `Date.today.strftime("%d/%m in the year %Y")` will render.

Comment: Thanks changed the accepted answer. Will use this in my Application :D

Answer (score 7):

You can replace `"-"` by `" "`:

```
Date.today.to_s.gsub("-", " ")
#=> "2016 04 11"
```

Comment: To replace certain characters, you can also use `tr('-', ' ')`. However, since `Date#to_s` calls `strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` under the hood, it's obviously better to omit the detour and just call `strftime` with the desired format as shown in [Anthony E's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36540881/477037).

Answer (score 3):

You can also try by a Ruby On Rails DateTime Helper Method `to_formatted_s(:number)`. As you tagged ruby on rails here

```
> Date.today.to_formatted_s(:number)
=> "20160411"
```

More [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_formatted_s)

Answer (score 0):

although **[@Anthony E's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540832/get-date-string-without-separators-in-rails#answer-36540881)** is correct, here is just option you can use **[String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split)** method also:

```
> Date.today.to_s.split('-').join(" ")
#=> "2016 04 11"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    puts 'Enter dob in dd-mm-yyyy format: '
    birthdate = Date.parse(gets)
    today = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    (today.to_s.split('-').join.to_i - birthdate.to_s.split('-').join.to_i) / 10000
```

Comment: Also this doesn't answer the question!